# How do I keep the file size of a GIF in check for an animated Google Ad?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif, image-quality, google

I designed 5 Google ad banners on photoshop ( first time creating animated gifs for Google Ad) and I wasn't aware of the requirements. The size of the banners were very big between 200 and 1500kb. I don't know how to optimize and reduce them on photoshop. I tried online with gif convertors/compressors but the image quality is decreasing greatly. What is the best way to reduce the banners to 15k0kb and keep the image quality. The banners are at 4fps, I've attached one of the banners for reference.[image]

Comment: GIFs are only suitable for relatively small images - like a couple of hundred px square at most. This is a huge image - 1250 x 2500px. That's why the file size is huge. Rescale the GIF smaller if you want a smaller file size.

Comment: I designed the banners on illustrator , the dimensions of the banner is half a page ( large skyscraper 300x600). I saved the illustrator file as a png and created the gif using the same dimensions. I did the same for leaderboard, large mobile banner etc. Should I reduce the size of the png? I hope I'm making sense

Comment: Your image isn't 300x600, it's 1250x2500px. Th size is too big in pixels. You should check with [Google Ad Manager Help](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/1100453?hl=en), and make your document one of those common sizes. Design it at the size you need. You could resize it smaller, but designing at the actual size needed is better,

Comment: When I designed it on illustrator the dimensions were 300x600...the feedback I received from Google didn't mention any issues about the actual dimensions but just the size and the duration of the gif. The dimensions on the Google ad manager help are exactly the same dimensions I used.

Comment: I've added an answer now with a fix.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit the title of your question to more accurately reflect what your issue is. Feel free to re-edit if I misrepresented anything.

Comment: Size will only match illustrator settings if you export at 72 ppi

Comment: Yes you're right, I exported it at 72 ppi,  it's exactly the same size on photoshop. This was the quickest way. It's just a bummer that the image quality is not so great . Thank you for your assistance , really appreciate it

Comment: @Vincent , that's exactly what I was trying to say. Spot on!

Answer (score 2):

The image size is way too big in pixel dimensions.  Generally, GIFs should only be a couple of hundred pixels wide/tall. They should be created at the size they will be viewed on a web page. Your image is 1250px x 2500px which is why the file size is so large. I suspect it has something to do with your export settings when you created the image initially since it's much bigger than you say it's supposed to be (300 x 600px).

Open the GIF in Photoshop CC/GIMP.

1. Convert to RGB (Photoshop CC should do this automatically when you open a GIF)
2. Rescale the image to 300 x 600px
3. Convert to Indexed colour - 256 colours is the best quality, enable dithering. (In Photoshop CC this happens automatically when you export an animated GIF using *File > Export > Save for Web* - use a large number of colours, again 256 is the best quality).
4. Export the animated GIF.

Here's one I did in GIMP. The file size is only around 72kb. Size 300x600px. You could get the file size smaller by using fewer colours in Indexed mode, but the quality will suffer.

[image]

Comment: I tried this solution and it flattened all my layers and removed my frames. I'm not quite sure why however I did manage to get the same dimensions by exporting it at 72 ppi in illustrator. My gif is now 61KB. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @Nathi This solution doesn't remove any frames. If it did, then I wouldn't have been able to make this edit. Make sure you are exporting as an animated GIF.